# Amcharts - generate serial chart with percentage values

Tags: charts, percentage, amcharts

I'm trying to generate serialChart with percentage values - e.g. on x axis we will have list of countries and on y axis we will have percentage values - from 0 to 100%. The bars present some values, summed to 100%. My problem is how to "tell" the graph what sum represents 100%? If I just add "recalculateToPercents":true to valueAxes object, the chart is generated with percentage values, but incorrectly:

http://www.test.go1.pl/tmp/amChart_error.png

The correct chart should look like this:

http://www.test.go1.pl/tmp/amChart_correct.png

Here is the example code (of the incorrect graph):

```
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
"type": "serial",
"theme": "none",    
"dataProvider": [{
    "country": "Spain",
    "visits": 20
}, {
    "country": "Netherlands",
    "visits": 40
}, {
    "country": "Russia",
    "visits": 5
}, {
    "country": "South Korea",
    "visits": 15
}, {
    "country": "Canada",
    "visits": 15
}, {
    "country": "Brazil",
    "visits": 5
}],
"valueAxes": [{
    "recalculateToPercents":true,          
    "gridColor":"#FFFFFF",
"gridAlpha": 0.2,
"dashLength": 0
}],
"gridAboveGraphs": true,
"startDuration": 1,
"graphs": [{
    "balloonText": "[[category]]: <b>[[value]]</b>",
    "fillAlphas": 0.8,
    "lineAlpha": 0.2,
    "type": "column",
    "valueField": "visits"      
}],
"chartCursor": {
    "categoryBalloonEnabled": false,
    "cursorAlpha": 0,
    "zoomable": false
},
"categoryField": "country",
"categoryAxis": {
    "gridPosition": "start",
    "gridAlpha": 0
}
```

});

Thank you in advance for your help :-)

Answer (score 3):

Try modifying the initialization code like this:

```
"balloonText": "[[category]]: <b>[[percents]]%</b>"
```

Note the keyword `[[percents]]`, here is another useful one: `[[total]]`.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to do the calculations yourself and use percent value as your value field. It's not that difficult:

percent = 100 * value / sum;

If you need to have real values in the tool-tip or the label, simply add real values to the data provider as well and use this field in the tool-tip or label, like: balloonText="[[category]]:[[realValue]] ([[value]]%)";

Answer (score 0):

Add this before `chart.ready(`

```
 var sum = 0;
 var sumSubdata = 0;
 for (var x in chartData) {                    
     sum += chartData[x].visits;     
 }

 for (var x in chartData) {
     chartData[x].share = Math.round(chartData[x].visits / sum * 100);
 }

// Add the below line

graph.labelText = "[[value]] ([[share]])%";
```